# How can I show the IDs and children of a JSON object?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, tree

The title doesn't sound clear, but I'm trying to show a `JSON` of a tree in an alert with `ID`s if an `ID` "has" children I will add the word children, when the "group" is done, I will add a `|` to show that the group is over, the problem is I can't find a way to add that `|` when the group is over.

**So, this tree:**

```
[
  {
    "name": "node1",
    "id": 1,
    "is_open" :true,
    "children": [
      {
        "name": "child2",
        "id": 3
      },
      {
        "name": "child2",
        "id": 7
      },
      {
        "name": "child1",
        "id": 2
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "name": "node1",
    "id": 4,
    "is_open": true,
    "children": [
      {
        "name": "child2",
        "id": 5
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

**Would be shown as:**

> 1,children,3,7,2|4,children,5|

Thus, I know that `ID:1` has `children` and they are `ID:3`, `ID:7` and `ID:2`, the group is over because of the `|` pipeline symbol and so on, but I don't know how to create something to check and add a `|`. Can you help me?

Thanks in advance.

**My Code:**

```js
var data = '[{"name":"node1","id":1,"is_open":true,"children":[{"name":"child2","id":3},{"name":"child2","id":7},{"name":"child1","id":2}]},{"name":"node1","id":4,"is_open":true,"children":[{"name":"child2","id":5}]}]';
var arrays = [];
//convert you string to object
//or you can simply change your first row.
data = $.parseJSON(data);
//function to loop the array
function listNodes(inputVal) {
  if (jQuery.isArray(inputVal)) {
    $.each(inputVal, function(i, elem) {
      arrays.push(elem.id);
      console.log(elem);
      if (jQuery.isArray(elem.children)) {
        arrays.push('children');
        listNodes(elem.children);
      }
    });
  }
}
listNodes(data);
alert(arrays);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

**UPDATE:**

What if I get two or more levels of children?

```
var data = JSON.parse('[{"name":"node1","id":1,"is_open":true,"children":[{"name":"child2","id":7},{"name":"child1","id":2,"is_open":true,"children":[{"name":"child2","id":3}]}]},{"name":"node1","id":4,"is_open":true,"children":[{"name":"child2","id":5}]}]');

var result = data.map(function(item) {
    return [item.id].concat('children', item.children.map(function(subitem) {
        return subitem.id;
    }));
}).join('|');

alert(result);
```

Comment: Add arrays.push('|'); when .each loop completes. This way it will also be easier to check the end of children in future.

Comment: you didn't need to add a new question for this.  http://jsfiddle.net/rejithrkrishnan/d4a37fbt/2/

Comment: @RejithRKrishnan the problem is, your code is doing that manually, it doesn't really detect anything

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need jQuery for this. For simplified version of the script you can use native [Array.prototype.map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) with [concat](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/concat) for this:

```js
var data = JSON.parse('[{"name":"node1","id":1,"is_open":true,"children":[{"name":"child2","id":3},{"name":"child2","id":7},{"name":"child1","id":2}]},{"name":"node1","id":4,"is_open":true,"children":[{"name":"child2","id":5}]}]');

var result = data.map(function(item) {
    return [item.id].concat('children', item.children.map(function(subitem) {
        return subitem.id;
    }));
}).join('|');

alert(result);
```

Or if you want to see how your own code might look when fixed:

```
function listNodes(inputVal) {
    if (jQuery.isArray(inputVal)) {
        $.each(inputVal, function (i, elem) {
            arrays.push(elem.id, ',');
            if (jQuery.isArray(elem.children)) {
                arrays.push('children,', elem.children.map(function(el) { return el.id; }));
            }
            arrays.push('|');
        });
    }
    arrays = arrays.join('');
}
```

Comment: Thanks for helping me, and I thought that was going to be neater using JQuery

Comment: that was a "like a boss" extreme lol, I wasn't expecting something so neat and with pure JavaScript plus showed my code when fixed, Goku is that you?

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```js
var data = [{"name":"node1","id":1,"is_open":true,"children":[{"name":"child2","id":3},{"name":"child2","id":7},{"name":"child1","id":2}]},{"name":"node1","id":4,"is_open":true,"children":[{"name":"child2","id":5}]}];

var str = '';
//1,children,3,7,2|4,children,5|
$.each(data, function(i, item){
    if(item.id){
      str += item.id + ',children,'
       $.each(item.children, function(j, child){
          if(child.id){
             str += child.id;
             str += (j >= item.children.length-1) ? "|" : ",";
          }
         
      });
    }
});

alert(str);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

I've written a recursive function for any type of json objects to print hirarchically.. its in java.. you can tweak it to use it..

```
static void printRecursive(JSONObject obj) {   
for(Object key:obj.keySet()) {
       //System.out.println(obj.get(key.toString()).getClass().getSimpleName());
        if(obj.get(key.toString()) instanceof JSONArray) {
            JSONArray aobj = ((JSONArray)obj.get(key.toString())); 

            for(int i=0;i<aobj.length();i++) {
                System.out.println(key.toString());
                printRecursive(aobj.getJSONObject(i));
            }
        }
        else
        if(obj.get(key.toString()) instanceof JSONObject) {
            System.out.println(key.toString());
            printRecursive((JSONObject)obj.get(key.toString()));
        }
        else
            System.out.println(key.toString()+" -> "+obj.get(key.toString()));
    }
}
```